# how to show s.th. under a List in android?

Tags: android

I have a ad which I want to show under my list. Currently it is over the list and works. The code looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >  

    <fragment android:name="xx.AdFragment"
              android:id="@+id/ad_fragment"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ExpandableListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

the problem is, when I put it under the List like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >  

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ExpandableListView>

    <fragment android:name="xx.AdFragment"
              android:id="@+id/ad_fragment"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

the app crashes and I get the error:

```
10-29 12:35:56.288: E/AndroidRuntime(13712): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-29 12:35:56.288: E/AndroidRuntime(13712): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxx/xxx.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ExpandableListView
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your java code you try to cast FrameLayout to ExpandableListView.

Maybe something like this

```
ExpandableListView el = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
```

though I don't see any FrameLayout in your xml.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will not work, since you have a linear layout. When the ExpandableListView will take the whole height of the parent (your linearlayout) your Ad will be out of the screen. So it's better to use RelativeLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/ad_fragment"
        android:name="xx.AdFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ad_fragment" >

    </ExpandableListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```